# How can I control the location of table1 (table1 package) tables in RMarkdown pdf document?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I would like to intersperse tables created using the R table1 package with text and headers in an RMarkdown pdf document. Instead of placing the headers/text and tables in the correct order, the text all appears at the beginning of the document, followed by all of the tables. How can I correct this?

Here's a small RMarkdown example that creates this error:

````
---
title: "Example"
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(table1)
```

## R Markdown

This document will illustrate the issue I'm encoutering with table1 in RMarkdown.

```{r createdata, echo=FALSE}
# create two table1 summary tables using mtcars dataset (built-in R dataset)
df <- mtcars

df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
df$gear <- factor(df$gear)
label(df$mpg) <- "Mileage"
label(df$cyl) <- "Cylinders"
label(df$hp) <- "Horsepower"
label(df$gear) <- "Number of Forward Gears"
label(df$wt) <- "Weight"

units(df$mpg) <- "miles/(US)gallon"
units(df$wt) <- "1000 pounds"

caption1 <- "Motor Trend Road Test Stats, grouped by number of forward gears"

summary1 <- table1(~ mpg + hp + wt | gear, data=df,
    overall=c(right="Total"), caption=caption1)

caption2  <- "Motor Trend Road Test Stats, grouped by number of cylinders"
summary2 <- table1(~ mpg + hp + wt + gear | cyl, data=df,
    overall=c(right="Total"), caption=caption2)

```

## Heading info here

Additional text 

```{r firsttable, echo=FALSE}
summary1
```

## Another heading 

More desciption

```{r secondtable, echo=FALSE}
summary2
```
````

The resulting document looks like this:

[image]

but I would like for it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `table1::t1kable()` to convert the `table1` table into a `kable` table and then use `kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")` to keep your table in the exact position.

````
---
title: "Example"
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(table1)
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

```{r createdata, echo=FALSE}
# create two table1 summary tables using mtcars dataset (built-in R dataset)
df <- mtcars

df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
df$gear <- factor(df$gear)
label(df$mpg) <- "Mileage"
label(df$cyl) <- "Cylinders"
label(df$hp) <- "Horsepower"
label(df$gear) <- "Number of Forward Gears"
label(df$wt) <- "Weight"

units(df$mpg) <- "miles/(US)gallon"
units(df$wt) <- "1000 pounds"

caption1 <- "Motor Trend Road Test Stats, grouped by number of forward gears"

summary1 <- table1(~ mpg + hp + wt | gear, data=df,
    overall=c(right="Total"), caption=caption1)

caption2  <- "Motor Trend Road Test Stats, grouped by number of cylinders"
summary2 <- table1(~ mpg + hp + wt + gear | cyl, data=df,
    overall=c(right="Total"), caption=caption2)

```

## Heading info here

```{r firsttable, echo=FALSE}
t1kable(summary1) |>
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```

## Another heading 

```{r secondtable, echo=FALSE}
t1kable(summary2)|>
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```
````

---

[image: table1 tables in a fixed position]

---

And I will recommend exploring the [table1 package vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-latex.pdf) for pdf and docx documents.